# MessageboxResult is Cancel when user clicks back button

Tags: windows-phone-7, messagebox, back-button

I noticed that if some `MessageBox` appears and you even just have a OK button on it and the user clicks the back button from Windows Phone 7, you will receive `Cancel` in `MessageBoxResult`.

Anybody experienced it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
        MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("something", "something", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        if (m == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("cancelled!");
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not cancelled!");
        }
```

Edit: Just found some information [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using)

An excerpt

> When the user closes the MessageBox in a non-standard manner (e.g. by
>   pressing the Back button), the result that is automatically passed as
>   a response is MessageBoxResult.Cancel, even if no Cancel button is
>   pressed.

From what I can tell from the article, `MessageBoxResult.Cancel` is what you get when using Windows Phone 7.
 But, when tested in a `Windows Phone 7.1(Mango)` application, I got a `MessageBoxResult.None`

Comment: user clicked the back button from wp7, we receive cancel in messageboxresult, as there was no cancel button in messagebox. why?

Comment: Could you post your code for the messageboxresult? I could not replicate your issue with the above code. I'm getting "not cancelled!".

Comment: MessageBoxResult mbr = MessageBox.Show("some message"); In debuging - i am getting cancel in mbr

Comment: Like @Heinrich Ulbricht said, I am getting `None` and `OK` when pressing `back` and `okay` respectively. Could you post a little more relevant code? This is certainly weird.

Comment: i have posted the single line code. in previous comments, i think it might be emulator issue, i need to verify it on device

Comment: See my edit. I think it has to do with the versions of the Windows Phone OS.

Comment: Yes, that was Windows Phone OS Version.

Answer (score 2):

The result is actually `MessageBoxResult.None`.

Depending on how you check the result it might either *appear* cancelled or OK. If you do it like [abhinav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8306750/56658) then it will seem like OK. You are probably checking for `m = OK` - then it will seem like cancelled in your code.